# Solr facet by id and get names

Tags: solr

I have documents of `Product`s and simplified schema is like this

```json
{
   "product_id":363044,
   "model":"iPhone 12 mini 64GB",
   "brand.manufacturer_id":17,
   "brand.name":"Apple"
},
{
   "product_id":363045,
   "model":"iPhone 11 Pro 256GB",
   "brand.manufacturer_id":17,
   "brand.name":"Apple"
}
```

This is the json I post to get brands facet.

```json
{
  "limit": 0,
  "facet": {
    "brands": {
      "type": "terms",
      "field": "brand.manufacturer_id",
      "limit": 6,
    }
  }
}
```

and the result I get is all `brand.manufacturer_id`s and the `count` which is cool and I want both of them.

What I want to have in addition is `brand.name` beside the `brand.manufacturer_id`. Is it possible with Solr facet?

Comment: Do you have different `brand.name`'s with the same value (i.e. same name, different id)? What kind of field type is `brand.name`?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes there can be multiple `name` (string field) with different `brand.manufacturer_id`. That's why I'm trying to group by `brand.manufacturer_id` and not by `brand.name`

Comment: @MatsLindh In addition, I want both `name` and `id` to generate a response for the client.

Comment: If you want separate facets for those that have different ids, create a composite field in your document that contains `<id>-<name>`. Facet on this field, and split it before returning it to your view / in your HTML. That way you'll have both values available and you'll still have efficient faceting. This field should have the `string` type, and would only be used for faceting and for limiting with `fq` based on a selected facet.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks I'll give a try.